# MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException on mapping @onetomany unidirectional mapping in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities having unidirectional onetomany relationship these are

> Entity 1

```
public class Jeans implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@OneToMany
private List<ColorAndPattern>  colorAndPatterns;

}
```

> Entity 2

```
public class ColorAndPattern implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

private String description;

private String background;

private boolean enabled;

private int gender;

}
```

I am using hibernates default mapping so this will result in the generation of a seperate table named "jeans+colorandpattern" for onetomany mapping

> Bussiness Method

I am using hibernate's save method to persist entity

```
@Override
    public int addJeans(Jeans jeans) {

    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(jeans);
    return jeans.getId();
    }
```

However when i try to add the same colorandPattern to a different jeans i am getiing

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UK_la26iue5ciou6o4dy2gc23tlo'

i have gone through the hibernates documentation  and find out that the in such cases hibernate added the unique constraint to child entity however i didnt want that how to override this behaviour or is there a better way

Comment: So each Jeans  has an id. And each ColorAndPattern  has a foreign key to link it to some jeans. So obviously you can only use a ColorAndPattern   with one Jeans (that's what "one to many" is all about). Don't you want a "many to many" relationship?

Comment: Thank you sir it works you are right thats manytomany relationship